# getch() doesnt produce the expected result

Tags: c++, ncurses, getch

I am on ncurses.I am working on a program that starts a timer when I press enter. I use this code:

```
        while(( ch = wgetch(w)) != 'q' )
        { 
            switch( ch ) {
            ...

            case ENTER: /*timer is expected to start by a function*/

        }
```

However, I need to hold down the Enter key to make the timer start. What I would like is to simply press the Enter key to start the timer. How can I solve this? I have the timer function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set `nodelay` to `FALSE` and called `cbreak()` so that `wgetch()` blocks, wait for the next character typed, and return it.

```
nodelay(w, FALSE);
cbreak();
```

It's been awhile since I used ncurses, but if I recall correctly, that should do it. Let me know.

Comment: When I did false, true; it worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Hakan Demir - You are welcome!